# How to export multiple images from Photos on my disk?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I imported lots of images in the Photos app.

How can I export the selected ones on my disk? What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On El Capitan,

Choose the photos and videos you want to export, by clicking on them while holding down <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>, then do `Photos > File > Export`

Comment: Yes, they hid it in a menu, they don't offer it through the right click context menu,